# Android camera intent confusion

Tags: android, android-camera

I am working on an app in which i have to click a pic a pic and save it to a specified folder. I am using **android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE** in intent to invoke the  camera .I am done with coding and my activity is working fine.But now i have a question in my mind that whether i should stick with this code or i should use the code given [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/CameraPreview.html).Need your precious suggestions on this topic.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just click a picture and save it to a specified folder nothing more then You can use `Intent` and call `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, it easy to let handle on camera activity do your stuff,

And If your application has some serious deep work with camera when you want to modify preview screen size, and all those things,(For this you have to handle all things like to manage camera, and when to release it, check for don't freeze main UI..) then you have to go with the code you suggested...

Choice is yours.....

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the code from [your link](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/CameraPreview.html).
Because most of the stock camera apps don't work as expected with Image Capture. For example the Galaxy S2 and most other Samsung and HTC phones give you the picture bytes back and also save the picture in the standard DCIM Folder on SD-Card, if you want it or not.

Comment: Android provide a nice way Intent to use built-in Camera application for your less code efforts requirements and in many apps people use this and its also works fine..

Answer (score 0):

```
public void imageFromCamera() {
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
        Log.d(TAG, "No SDCARD");
    } else {
        mImageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"MyApp",  
            "PIC"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg");
        mTempImagePath = mImageFile.getAbsolutePath();
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(mImageFile));
        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
    }
}
```

this what u r searching i am thinking..